# gmailR error "Only AF_INET sockets are currently supported on jython"

Tags: python, r, sockets, notifications

I've been using gmailR in R to send emails from R without problems, but since a week it has been malfunctioning. Sometimes it works, but most times it doesn't. This is by the way the the Trinker package from github (and not the CRAN gmailr!): https://github.com/trinker/gmailR

This is my script:

```
library(gmailR)
chartime <- as.character(Sys.time())
email_test <- function(chartime){
  gmail("sjorsvanheuveln@gmail.com", password="************", subject = "Test No New Projects",
        message = paste("Testing time at",chartime), from = "sjorsvanheuveln@gmail.com",
        attachment = NULL, server = "smtp.gmail.com:587", username = "sjorsvanheuveln@gmail.com",
        confirmBeforeSend = FALSE, clear.username = FALSE)}
email_test(chartime)
```

And here is the error:

```
Error in jython.exec(rJython, mail) : 
  Only AF_INET sockets are currently supported on jython 
7 stop(python.exception) 
6 jython.exec(rJython, mail) 
5 email.helper(to = list(to[i]), from = list(from), subject = subject, 
    message = message, attachment = atts[[i]], username = username, 
    password = password, server = server, confirmBeforeSend = confirmBeforeSend) 
4 FUN(1L[[1L]], ...) 
3 lapply(seq_along(to), function(i) {
    email.helper(to = list(to[i]), from = list(from), subject = subject, 
        message = message, attachment = atts[[i]], username = username, 
        password = password, server = server, confirmBeforeSend = confirmBeforeSend) ... 
2 gmail("sjorsvanheuveln@gmail.com", password = "**********", subject = "Test No New Projects", 
    message = paste("Testing time at", chartime), from = "sjorsvanheuveln@gmail.com", 
    attachment = NULL, server = "smtp.gmail.com:587", username = "sjorsvanheuveln@gmail.com", 
    confirmBeforeSend = FALSE, clear.username = FALSE) 
1 email_test(chartime)
```

And here is my session info:

```
   R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] nl_NL.UTF-8/nl_NL.UTF-8/nl_NL.UTF-8/C/nl_NL.UTF-8/nl_NL.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gmailR_1.0    rJython_0.0-4 rjson_0.2.15  rJava_0.9-7  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.3  XML_3.98-1.3
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I figured out that this error is probably only popping op when I'm at work connected to a different router. How can I overcome the problem and make it work there?

Answer (score 2):

Not supporting AF_INET6 was fixed Jython 2.5.2, see http://bugs.jython.org/issue1210 (The fact that your problem appears with a different router very much suggests that it is IPv4 vs IPv6.) However, rJython bundles an older version of the Jython jar. Perhaps this can be upgraded, even if not to 2.7?

It might be worthwhile contacting the maintainers of the rJython package to do so.